# VS 2005 : how do you update dataset source without sql server connection

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, dsn

I have an existing project written in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2005 communicating to a SQL Server 2005 database. The database was migrated to a sql server 2008 r2 on a different physical server so the dataset's server name needs to be updated.  I do not have access to the database anymore.  is there a way to just update the server name without invoking the dataset wizard and requiring a connection to the database?

thanks in advance

UPDATE: 
I tried to created a new project with just a button with the command calling the following subroutine to test the connection from a windows app to the sql server database.  here is the sub:

```
Public Conn as New ADODB.Connection 
Public Sub PubSubConnectToDB() 
   Conn.Open("Server=w2k54\newdb; Database=Subscribers;","kuser", "Pass5555") 
end sub
```

the error i receive is

> COM Exception was not handled :
>   [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(
>   Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist
>   or access denied.

I am able to created a system dsn on the same server with the same credentials and test the connection successfully.  any ideas?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the server name in the connection string. Normally this should be located in your App.config.

Comment: that didn't work for me.  it said it was unable to find the server.  any ideas?